# Очереди в Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, очередь

Не могу добиться выполнения очередей.

Указал в `.env`:

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

Создал таблицу: `jobs`

В коде пишу:

```
dispatch((new \App\Jobs\SendEmail($userMail, $data))->onQueue('emails'));
```

В консоли запускаю команду `php artisan queue:listen` или `php artisan queue:work`

Но ничего не происходит. Только добавляется новая запись в базу и на этом всё...

Странно, что команды в консоли просто висят, не выводя ничего на экран

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Укажите тип очереди при вызове воркера, в вашем примере в записываете задачи в очередь `emails`.

Вызовите воркер следующим образом:

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=emails
```

И если не получиться ничего с командой выше - проверьте что в таблицу очередей пишется.